# Writing functions in R with vectors

Tags: r

I am having trouble understanding how to write a function in R for use with vectors. For the question:

Write an R function to determine if two sets, A and B, represented as integer vectors are disjoint. If they are disjoint, display elements of set A otherwise display elements of set B.

I understand the basic format for function and conditional statements, for example:

```
name <- function(x){ 
           if (x>3) print("x is greater than 3") 
           else print ("x not greater than 3") 
        }
```

however, for the above question, I don't know how to go about doing something similar, but with vectors as the arguments. Any answers??

Comment: Just curious: is this a homework problem?

Comment: The problem as stated is not about vectors: it's about set theory.  That should give a strong hint as to what R functions would be useful. (and yes, I know we all use the term "vector" pretty loosely, but here the order of values in `A` or `B` is not relevant, so they really don't qualify as vectors)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you have it will work, just replacing the single value with the name of the vector. You will have to be mindful that you are now dealing with a series of numbers and not just a single value though. Using functions like `any` and `all` may be of use to you in doing comparisons (see `?any` and `?all` for descriptions).

```
vec1 <- 1:3
print(vec1)
vec1

vec2 <- 2:4
print(vec2)
vec2

grthan3 <- function(vectorname) { 
if (any(vectorname > 3)) print("1 or more values > 3")  else
                         print("no such luck")  
}

grthan3(vec1)
#[1] "no such luck"
grthan3(vec2)
#[1] "1 or more values > 3"
```

Like @joran, i'm mindful of not just solving the problem if this is a homework issue.